# How to parameterize some emprical data

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I would like to describe a bunch of data that I have collected as a function of two variables.  The data is phytoplankton absorption in my local area that has changed in concentration.  The data looks similar to this image.

[image: Phytoplankton absorption]

Phytoplankton will vary in absorption greatly around 440 (nm) and 665 (nm)  [Actually it is more complicated than that but for my purposes it is fine.] The total absorption will increase with concentration.  It will increase non-linearly as their are shading effects and chlorophyll packaging effects.

I was thinking that it may be possible to come up with a two component empirical model, possibly? based around a basis vector (or the mean value of lots of measurements) and somehow describing the variance around 440 and 665 nm to scale the total absorption.

I don't really know where to start looking. These so called 'bio-optical' models are comon for CDOM and Particle scattering but they are much simpler to describe by fitting curves to their much simpler shapes.

Any help regards to what books to read or what to begin searching would be appreciated.  I am not a mathematician, so I am not great at this stuff but I did do Vector calc and linear algebra at uni.

[EDIT]  sorry lack of axis.  X axis is wavelength in nm 440 and 665 are the two peaks.